# How do I create list of polylines for gps?

Tags: java, android, gps, maps, polyline

how I need to do a GPS tracker but in principle I need to make a list of fixed points to test the issue of passing the points that trace on the map, could advise me how to do it. I already understand how to add one by one but I am getting complicated the list and the theme of the functions that polyline has

Answer (score 0):

To create a polyline you can do it like that :

```
 Polyline polyline1 = googleMap.addPolyline(new      PolylineOptions()
                   .clickable(true)
                   .add(
                        new LatLng(-35.016, 143.321),
                        new LatLng(-34.747, 145.592),
                        new LatLng(-34.364, 147.891),
                        new LatLng(-33.501, 150.217),
                        new LatLng(-32.306, 149.248),
                        new LatLng(-32.491, 147.309)));
```

And then you can add it to your google map .

For more informations about google map and polyline,  check the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/polygon-tutorial)

**edit**

If you have a list of `Latlng` you can use a loop to add them to the polyline .

```
for(int i=0;i<path.length;++)
{
  polyline1.add(path[i]);
}
```

Comment: I do understand that but what I want is to pass a list of points and add them to the polyline, read the documentation and indicate to add it only one by one

Comment: a question the loop should not be with i and j since they would be two points or with only one already working?

Comment: My friend your list will be a list of Latlng object , which means a list of point(x,y) and when you call list.get(i) you will get your latlng object !

Comment: to ok then if I want to do something like that it works
LatLng [] path =
         new LatLng [] {
           new LatLng (-33.865382, 151.192861),
           new LatLng (-33.865837, 151.193376),
           new LatLng (-33.866745, 151.19373),
           new LatLng (-33.867128, 151.19344),
           new LatLng (-33.867547, 151.193676),
           new LatLng (-33.867841, 151.194137),
           new LatLng (-33.868224, 151.194116)
         }  Thank you